# Google Maps showing orange tiles for satellite view

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I noticed this morning that the GMSMapView and GoogleMap of our iOS and Android apps are starting to show tiles with an abnormal orange tint. I've attached a screenshot of the app that captures the original tiles being replaced by orange tiles.

I'm wondering whether anyone else is seeing this issue, and whether there is some configuration I missed that can get the map back to pulling the original tiles.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KyhO.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Those tiles come from a different (presumably newer) series of sat images, taken from a different angle with a different cam at a different time of day etc. 
Under these circumstances, minor differences in tint are not unexpected.